# Strange behaviour mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table with a timestamp field including these values:

```
2012-03-12 12:53:34
2012-03-12 12:54:11 
2012-03-12 01:02:37
2012-03-12 01:03:04
2012-03-12 01:03:46
```

My query is the following

```
SELECT * FROM 
(Select MESSAGE_OF_USER,MESSAGE_TIME as time,CONVERSATION_ID 
 from poem_authors_messages 
 where (CONVERSATION_ID='2' or CONVERSATION_ID='1') and 
       MESSAGE_TIME>'2012-03-12 12:53:34' 
 ORDER BY time DESC) poem_authors_messages 
ORDER BY time ASC
```

Notice the time. It should give me these results

```
2012-03-12 12:54:11 
2012-03-12 01:02:37
2012-03-12 01:03:04
2012-03-12 01:03:46
```

but instead i get

```
2012-03-12 12:54:11
```

why is this happening?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 of your times are AM and not PM.  This means that they're ***not*** greater than your filter time...

```
                     |  MESSAGE_TIME>'2012-03-12 12:53:34'
---------------------+--------------------------------------
2012-03-12 01:02:37  |  No
2012-03-12 01:03:04  |  No
2012-03-12 01:03:46  |  No
2012-03-12 12:54:11  |  Yes
2012-03-12 13:02:37  |  Yes
2012-03-12 13:03:04  |  Yes
2012-03-12 13:03:46  |  Yes
```

Comment: You are right Dems i was saving in 12 hour format not in 24 this is the right line needed $date = date('y-m-d H:i:s'); - H makes 24 hour model available. I was using the small h which is for 12 hour model.

Answer (score 1):

You have said to mysql: select only if time greater then `'2012-03-12 12:53:34'`

`and MESSAGE_TIME>'2012-03-12 12:53:34'`

Change `and MESSAGE_TIME>'2012-03-12 12:53:34'` to `and MESSAGE_TIME <= '2012-03-12 12:53:34'`

To get

```
2012-03-12 12:53:34
2012-03-12 01:02:37
2012-03-12 01:03:04
2012-03-12 01:03:46
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the AM/PM stuff? There is no information on that in your Mail. Maybe your assumption is just wrong and the sql is right...

However: Please provide your DB Version... Oracle?

Comment: The question is tagged as MySQL, not Oracle.